# rails/devise: heroku app not recording user's ip addresses correctly?

Tags: heroku, ip

All of the users in my app's Users table have signin IP addresses that are 'private' 10.x.x.x

So while devise is recording the IP address of a user when they signin, it appears to ACTUALLY be recording some sort of heroku internal IP address, probably related to the fancy grid architecture routing.

Does anyone know how my heroku-hosted app can record the actual incoming IP address?

Comment: Interestingly enough I've just looked at one of my apps on Heroku, I haven't made any changes and my devise last_sign_in_ip is populated with my current external IP address. Few things to note, I'm running on Cedar stack, Rails 3.1.1, Devise 1.4.3 from the looks of things.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to.

Something like this should yield the proper IP address:

```
ip = env[‘HTTP_X_REAL_IP’] ||= env[‘REMOTE_ADDR’]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, and if it works, try to figure out how to get Devise to grab the 'right' IP address...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your app is behind a proxy or something like that.

Look at this patch: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1398

It should solve the problem.